# Is there a way to "watch" an IndexedDB record so I can respond when it's been changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, indexeddb

I am building an Angular + TypeScript application that uses IndexedDB for storing data locally.

---

I have an Angular directive that sets the value of a `scope` variable to be some data that was returned from an IndexedDB request. It's pretty simple and does something like:

### **Directive A:**

```
// getGroup() is making the requests to IndexedDB:
this.dataService.getGroup().then((groupOne) => {
    this.scope.items = groupOne.items;
});
```

The view for my directive loops through each of these items:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</div>
```

---

I have another Angular directive (let's call it **Directive B**) that is updating/inserting the `items` associated with `groupOne`.

### **Directive B:**

```
groupOne.items.push("a new item");
this.dataService.updateGroup(groupOne).then(() => {
   // groupOne has been changed!
   // how can I let Directive A know about this, so Directive A can update its scope.items?
});
```

---

Of course, **Directive A** does not know about the changes **Directive B** made to `groupOne` unless it does another request. And therefore, my view is "static".

I know I could wrap **Directive A**'s IndexedDB request into an `interval` and be checking for updates, but that seems like a strange way to solve this problem.

Is there a way with IndexedDB to be notified of this change? Is there something Angular provides that could help with this (something similar to `$scope.$watch()`) ?

Comment: Try to google for Angular Emitter. In more general language this is called "Listener pattern".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not yet a way to do this with pure IndexedDB but it is being prototyped. The name is "Observers". You can try to use the [polyfill](https://github.com/dmurph/indexed-db-observers) if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 3):

It's not *quite* what I wanted (which is why I accepted dgrogan's answer), but in case anyone who stumbles upon this question is curious about what I ended up doing:

- Manually `broadcasting` a custom event whenever I change `groupOne` (or anything else I care about) solves my problem for now.
- I used `$scope.$broadcast()` from a controller (that's managing
  a few interactions between directives) to let **Directive A** know about
  the change **Directive B** made using `$scope.$on()`.
- This article was really helpful: http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/